# React wrong console output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know what is causing the error in this code because when I try to delete a task, it correctly removes it from the list. However, the console says that the task deleted was the most recently added task.

[image: I try to delete "upload slides" task]

[image: upload slides task deleted but console displays that lecture recording task was deleted. lecture recording is the most recently added task]

```
import React from "react";

class ToDo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Added to do: " + this.props.item.name)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("Deleted to do: " + this.props.item.name)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.item.selected} onChange={() => this.props.selectItem(this.props.dataKey)}/>
                {this.props.item.name} 
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default ToDo;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [{name: "upload slides", selected: false},
                    {name: "grade lab activities", selected: false},
                    {name: "lecture recording", selected: false}],
            itemToBeAdded: ""
        };

        this.updateItemToBeAdded = this.updateItemToBeAdded.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
        this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    }

    updateItemToBeAdded(e) {
        this.setState({itemToBeAdded: e.target.value});
    }

    addItem(e) {
        if(this.state.itemToBeAdded === "") {
            return;
        }

        var newItem = {name: this.state.itemToBeAdded, selected: false};
        this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, newItem]});
    }

    removeItem(e) {
        var items = this.state.items;
        var updatedItems = items.filter((item) => {return !item.selected});
        this.setState({items: updatedItems});
    }

    selectItem(indexOfItem) {
        var items =  this.state.items;
        var selectedItem = items[indexOfItem];

        items[indexOfItem].selected = !selectedItem.selected;
        this.setState({items: items});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="to-do-list">
                <input onChange={this.updateItemToBeAdded}></input>
                <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
                <h1>{this.props.user}'s To Do List</h1>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                            <ToDo key={index} dataKey={index} item={item} selectItem={this.selectItem}/>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
                <button onClick={this.removeItem}>Delete Item</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

I tried different things such as modifying the removeItem function in such a way that it creates a copy of the items array before filtering it.

```
removeItem(e) {
  const items = [...this.state.items]; 
  const updatedItems = items.filter((item) => !item.selected);
  this.setState({ items: updatedItems });
}
```

I also tried a similar attempt in the selectItem function.

```
selectItem(indexOfItem) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const items = [...prevState.items];
    const selectedItem = items[indexOfItem];
    items[indexOfItem] = { ...selectedItem, selected: !selectedItem.selected };
    return { items };
  });
}
```

After these changes, the console still prints out a message saying that I deleted the most recently added task even if I deleted a different one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Can you check this link ? https://blog.devgenius.io/react-class-function-todo-lists-6361ae06369b

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are providing `index` as a `key` in following line.

```
<ToDo key={index} dataKey={index} item={item} selectItem={this.selectItem}/>
```

Keys are used in React to identify which items in the list are changed, updated, or deleted. When you remove some item(s) from the list, indexes change for older item(s)

After the filter in `removeItem(e)` the state items array has fewer items, React doesn't find the last `key` (last index no longer present in the items array) as compared to previous state array so `componentWillUnmount()` runs for the last item, causing bug.

Index as a key often leads to subtle and confusing bugs.
You can read about this here https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys